Fix this numpy-function so it accepts multidimensional inputs
I am trying to compute the following function:
geo-decay-function:

in numpy, has to be vectorized. The catch in this case is that it should work for multidimensional inputs. E.g., x having dimensions (999, 20) where the second dimension represents t in the function above. h will have one dimension which matches with the first dimension of x and should be mapped towards the first dimension of x, h would have dimensions (999,) in the case above, the output in this case should be of dimension (999, 20).
If x would have been 1d, the following code works for theta being 2d and 3d (not considering L):
def adstock_geometric(x, h):
    axis = n if (n := len(np.array(h).shape) - 1) > 0 else None
    return ((h**np.arange(x.size)) * x).cumsum(axis)

However, if we have a 2d x where the first dimension should be mapped towards the first dimension of h i dont see how we can do it besides looping over each dimension(thus an range(999) loop in the case above).. can someone aid me on this matter?
Another 1d solution is:
def adstock_geometric(x: np.array, h: np.array):
    x_decayed = np.zeros_like(x)
    x_decayed[0] = x[0]

    for xi in range(1, len(x_decayed)):
        x_decayed[xi] = x[xi] + h * x_decayed[xi - 1]

    return x_decayed

which is really slow however.. and will not work for 2d x. Furthermore, I am unsure on how to incorporate L..
update
this below seem to work but it is not vectorized:
def adstock_geometric(x, theta, L=7, normalize=False):
    result = []
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        cumsum = 0
        wcumsum = 0
        for l in range(min(i + 1, L)):
            w = theta ** l
            cumsum += w * x[:, i - l]
            wcumsum += w
        if not normalize:
            result.append(cumsum)
        else:
            result.append(cumsum / wcumsum)

    return np.array(result).T


It would be helpful if you provided a small set of given input values (e.g. specific random values initialized with a fixed seed) and the corresponding output that you would expect. This would make it easier to reproduce what you attempt to achieve and maybe provide a solution. Also, what is theta? It is not used in the image of the equation that you provided.

((h**np.arange(x.shape[0]))[:, None] * x) should produce x.shape result.  Or maybe you want h[:,None]**np.arange(x.shape[1]) *x.

Anyway, I figured that theta should be the same as h in the equation, and I created some test data myself that checks against the last adstock_geometric() implementation from your question. See my proposed answer.

Once you realize that you can calculate both your numerator and your denominator by a discrete convolution along the last axis, vectorization becomes possible:
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import oaconvolve

def adstock_vectorized(x, theta, L, normalize):  # Proposed implementation
    assert theta.shape == x.shape[:-1]  # Check shape compatibility
    l = x.shape[-1]  # Same as `length` below
    w = theta[..., np.newaxis] ** np.arange(min(L, l))  # Create `w`
    # Convolve with `x` (numerator) and ones (denominator) along last axis
    num = oaconvolve(w, x, mode="full", axes=-1)[..., :l]
    denom = oaconvolve(w, np.ones_like(x), mode="full", axes=-1)[..., :l]
    return num / denom if normalize else num

def adstock_geometric(x, theta, L, normalize):  # From question (condensed)
    result = []
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        cumsum, wcumsum = 0, 0
        for l in range(min(i + 1, L)):
            w = theta ** l
            cumsum += w * x[:, i - l]
            wcumsum += w
        result.append((cumsum / wcumsum) if normalize else cumsum)
    return np.array(result).T

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
    num, length = 30, 10  # Create some demo data
    x, theta = rand.normal(size=(num, length)), rand.normal(size=num)
    
    for normalize in False, True:
        for L in range(1, length + 1):
            a_v = adstock_vectorized(x, theta, L=L, normalize=normalize)
            a_g = adstock_geometric(x, theta, L=L, normalize=normalize)
            assert np.allclose(a_v, a_g)

The proposed solution, adstock_vectorized(), should work for arbitrary numbers of dimensions, as long as your data lie along the last dimension.
Some more notes:

You can also try and use fftconvolve() instead of oaconvolve(). Either might be faster for your actual data. Unfortunately, you cannot use convolve() directly, as it misses the axes argument, which is crucial here.
Choosing a different random seed and different array sizes, you may find that the assertion in the last line occasionally fails. On all my checks, I could always only find that this was due to numerical error rather than actually different results.
As a further optimization: You can skip the calculation of the denominator (denom in my code, wcumsum in yours) if normalize is False.

